# Exercise #5 in Chapter 6 of Programming in C, "simple “printing” calculator"

Tags: c

### Exercise #5 in Chapter 6 of Programming in C, by Kochan

> Write a program that acts as a simple "printing" calculator. The program should allow the user to type in expressions of the form: `number operator`. The following operators should be recognized by the program: `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, `S`. `E`
>   - The `S` operator tells the program to set the "accumulator" to the typed-in number.
>   - The `E` operator tells the program that execution is to end.The arithmetic operations are performed on the contents of the accumulator with the number that was keyed in acting as the second operand.
>   The following is a "sample run" showing how the program should operate:
>
> ```
>    Begin Calculations
>         10 S            Set Accumulator to 10 
>         = 10.000000     Contents of Accumulator
>         2 /             Divide by 2 
>         = 5.000000      Contents of Accumulator
>         55 -            Subtract 55 
>         -50.000000
>         100.25 S        Set Accumulator to 100.25 
>         = 100.250000
>         4 *             Multiply by 4 
>         = 401.000000
>         0 E             End of program 
>         = 401.000000
>    End of Calculations.
> ```
>
> Make certain that the program detects division by zero and also checks for unknown operators.

If I enter `* 2` it returns `inf`. This is what I did:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    float number1, number2;
    char operator;

    do 
    {
        printf("Enter your number with S sign that set it as your accumulator \n");
        scanf("%f %c", &number1, &operator);

    } while (operator != 'S');


        do 
        {
            printf("Enter your expression with the correct format\n");
            scanf("%f %c", &number2, &operator); 

            if ( operator == '+' || operator == '-' || operator == '/' || operator == '*')
            {
                switch (operator)
                    {
                        case '+':
                            number1 = number1 + number2;
                            printf("=%.6f\n", number1);
                            break;
                        case '-':
                            number1 = number1 - number2;
                            printf("=%.6f\n", number1);
                            break;
                        case '*':
                            number1 = number1 * number2;
                            printf("=%.6f\n", number1);
                            break;
                        case '/':
                            if( number2 == 0) 
                                printf("Division by Zero\n");
                            else
                            {
                                number1 = number1 / number2;
                                printf("%.6f\n", number1);
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            printf("not a valid operator\n");
                            break;
                    }
            }
            else
                printf("Retry.\n");

        } while (operator != 'E'); 



    printf("End of Calculations\n");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time and read our introduction to new users on how to ask good questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think you need to show us exactly what you typed in, and exactly what the output was, just like you did with the "sample run".

Answer (score 1):

For the `scanf("%f %c", &number2, &operator);` statement, * is not a valid character for `%f`. The scanf fails but the do block tries again and again tries to read * into `%f`.

Replace the statement with

```
if ( ( scanf("%f %c", &number2, &operator)) != 2) {
    number2 = 1.0f;
    operator = 0;
    scanf ( "%*[^\n]");
}
```

scanf will return the number of items successfully read. If scanf does not return 2, then set the values to some appropriate value and `scanf ( "%*[^\n]);` will read and discard everything in the buffer that is not a newline.
Do something similar for the first scan for `number1`