# how to convert char containing operator into actual operator in C

Tags: c, operators

I want to ask if it is possible without using bunch of extra if statements convert char that contains an operator into an actual operator using like one or couple lines? What I would imagine looking is something like that:

Sorry for something stupid, I am just a starter.

```
char a;
scanf("%c", x);
if (x == '+' || x == '-' || x == '*' || x == '/')
a = b x c;
```

Comment: No, that's not possible without some kind of switch, lookup, or similar.

Comment: Aside: `scanf("%c", x);` ==> `scanf(" %c", &x);` (two changes).

Comment: Search for answers before posting questions. You might have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32294271/exercise-5-in-chapter-6-of-programming-in-c-simple-printing-calculator).

Comment: thank you for answers.
@Mogsdad that's pretty much what I did initially, just wanted to know if there is a shorter way.

Answer (score 1):

C is a compiled not an interpreted language - all the source is translated to machine level instructions at compile time, not at run-time, so generally it is not possible - at least not by any means that you should reasonably consider - most plausible means would look like virus or malware code behaviour.

What you could do is implement an expression evaluator like [this one](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/expression_evaluation.html) where an entire expression string is evaluated (not just the operator, but the operands as well) - essentially implementing an interpreter within your code.

If all you want is a one line expression to perform an operation on `b` and `c` selected by `x` then the following will do that:

```
a = x == '+' ? b + c : x == '-' ? b - c : x == '*' ? x * c : x == '/' ? x / c : 0 ;
```

though I'd strongly suggest splitting across multiple lines for readability:

```
 a = x == '+' ? b + c : 
                x == '-' ? b - c : 
                           x == '*' ? x * c : 
                                      x == '/' ? x / c : 
                                                 0 ;
```

though in truth I'd strongly suggest not doing that at all!  Note that while the above is strictly a *single expression* it is likely to be less or no more efficient than a switch/case, and probably identical to an if/else if.

As a beginner you should be striving for simple readable code - even if that code is longer.  When you become an expert, you will know that such code is most often folly.  You gain efficiency in coding by code reuse, not by writing shorter code - write once use often.  Shorter code is often less generic and therefore less reusable.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will have to have separate statements for each operator you wish to apply, whether that is done with 'if', 'switch/case' or a function-lookup table, the compiler is not going to perform any magic to turn a run-time decision into a compile-time choice.